# Create a Swagger 2.0 defined property with a specific hard-coded value

Tags: swagger

I'm creating a #definition in Swagger 2.0 for an OAuth JSON payload. `grant_type` is required, but must be a specific value (`password`).

How can I tell Swagger that the value of this property must be equal to `password`?

```
definitions:
  TokenRequest:
    required:
      - userId
      - password
      - grant_type
    properties:
      userId:
        type: string
      password:
        type: string
      grant_type:
        # here we need to describe that it must = 'password'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you would it define it like this:

```
definitions:
  TokenRequest:
    required:
      - userId
      - password
      - grant_type
    properties:
      userId:
        type: string
      password:
        type: string
      grant_type:
        type: string
        enum:
          - password
```

However, you should know that Swagger 2.0 has specific section to specify security attributes for your application, including the OAuth2 password flow. You can then set it globally for your API and override it if needed per operation. Alternatively, you can just declare it per operation.

For more information on it:

1. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#swaggerSecurityDefinitions
2. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#swaggerSecurity
3. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/fixtures/v2.0/json/resources/securityExample.json

Answer (score 0):

An alernative would be to use a pattern

```yaml
definitions:
  TokenRequest:
    required:
      - userId
      - password
      - grant_type
    properties:
      userId:
        type: string
      password:
        type: string
      grant_type:
        type: string
        pattern: ^password$
```

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#pattern